# Moving WordPress from GoDaddy to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to move a Wordpress blog hosted on a GoDaddy server to one hosted by Amazon. I want to transfer the SQL files so that the blog remains the same. Would I just have to transfer domain names or are there other steps I have to take?

Answer (score 4):

There is a lot more involved in doing this move.. See below the broad steps required:

- A EC2 Instance with a Linux OS of your choice, preferably one your familiar and comfortable with. Select an Instance type you believe will have sufficient resources to handle your website. Wordpress and PHP tend to like memory usage, so an instance type with at least 2GB of memory may be a good start. If you are able to confirm any performance figures from GoDaddy, this may help in your choice of instance type. See our instance type comparison at the below URL[2]. Note that, if your website is CPU intensive, select an instance type with at least 2 vCPU's to assist with performance.
- A FTP application installed on the Instance, to allow you to upload files to the instance as needed.
- On the EC2 Instance, you will install the LAMP Stack which is Apache, MySQL and PHP.
- You will configure a Apache vhost for your website, which needs to include the domain name for which Apache needs to serve requests as well as the document root for the website(the directory where your wordpress files are stored).
- In MySQL you will create a MySQL User and Database. You will assign the created MySQL user all priviliges to the created Database. You will then create a database backup from GoDaddy and then import it into the newly created MySQL Database on your instance.
- You can then upload a backup of all your website files to your EC2 instance and place them in the document root. Correct ownership and permissions on the uploaded files accordingly. You can then update your database connection string in your Wordpress configuration file.

Along the way you will run into things like having to manually update the mysql database name in the sql file to allow you to import it into your newly created database.. possible php version related issues with some plugins etc..

try this, and see if it works.. https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/

i have no experience with it, but it has great reviews and should have great support with that..

Answer (score 2):

Perfect decision to move from old Hosting Platforms to something new like AWS. Try using Amazon Lightsail for your Wordpress it's amazing.

To move any WordPress website/blog to another server as it is, you need to move both your Database as well as Wordpress Contain to the new server.

For this there are 3 options:
1. With plugin: All in One migrate (but sometimes, migrating a website using the plugin just doesn't work)

So you can do it using:
2.Tools

3.You can also choose to take a manual backup of the database using phpMyAdmin and WordPress contain using any FTP Client program and restore them to your new server.

If you want to see how it is done you can Check the link below, I have provided the complete step by step migration process to migrate Wordpress to Amazon Lightsail.

https://www.udemy.com/quick-install-or-migrate-wordpress-to-aws-lightsail-2018/

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

I honestly think it's worth paying the difference to stay on GoDaddy. AWS is ok for all of the features, but having to go through 10 steps and wait 3 days every time I need something done is ridiculous.  If I wanted to completely program my entire interface from the ground up, I'd get out of Web Development and go into Software Engineering.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon has a new(er) [Lightsail](https://amazonlightsail.com/) service which makes such migrations easier. This blog article is a pretty decent tutorial on the process: [Migrating my WordPress Blog to Amazon AWS Lightsail](http://www.adrianmilne.com/migrating-wordpress-blog-amazon-aws-lightsail/). As of today (8/17/17), they offer a 30-day free trial to test it first, and after that it is as low as $5 a month.

Answer (score 1):

I totally understand your question.

What you need to do is to copy your existing document root (the website files and folders) after that, prepare a dump for your database Wordpress database.

Third step would be sending this over sftp/ftp rsync or scp to the other host.

In the other host you will need to install the LEMP or LAMP Stack, depending on what you need and finally, restoring the files where they should be and restore the database from the dumped file you created.

Make sure to create your vhost either on apache or Nginx.

And for the DNS you can try following the steps on my blog to do it: https://www.clickittech.com/aws/migrate-godaddy-to-aws-route53/

I hope that you can do it with this information.